# How to print border around mutliple pages per sheet with the Ubuntu system print dialog

Tags: printing, system, dialog, borders

The Ubuntu system print dialog has a provision for printing multiple pages per sheet, but it doesn't have an option to draw a border around the pages.  This seems to be the case for most printer models I have tried. One can print borders from the command line with `lp -o page-border`.  It can be done by CUPS, so it seems strange for this option not to be in the print dialog.

How does one get a border around the pages with multiple pages per sheet using the system print dialog?

I've also searched for a way to add this option to a PPD file, as I've customized PPDs in the past.  Surprisingly, I haven't been able to find anything about how to add the option for creating a border around those multiple pages to a PPD.  Is multiple sheets per page done by a CUPS extension, or is this a native PostScript function?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You've not provided clues as to which Ubuntu product or release. Are you wanting this for a Ubuntu Server system? Ubuntu Desktop? what release?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS desktop

Comment: Please add details to your question; as that is what is answered, the purpose of comments is for readers commenting on the question to the Original Poster, who will clarify, add additional details etc. on their question & comments will get removed. It's the question that is answered, which is still without release details; your *comment* mentions two different releases??